# What's the strongest material in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, composition

Once I read that the strongest thing in the Marvel Universe is the Silver Surfer's skin, followed by the Mjolnir and Adamantium. Is this right? And, if so, what makes them so special?

Comment: The power of friendship.    That was dumb, don't laugh at that.

Comment: The Hulk's purple shorts appear to be made of an indestructible substance capable of withstanding a nuclear blast.  They're also infinitely stretchy.

Comment: ... until next year, when they introduce something even stronger...

Comment: Deusexmachinastone

Comment: Define "strength".

Comment: Each comic seems to have its own supermaterial that's better than all the others _in one very specific context_.  To that I say, GPa or GTFO.

Comment: The material in superhero costumes that covers the crotch area, and (for ladies) the breasts. That hardly ever is completely destroyed, no matter how much else of the costume is wrecked.

Comment: I think including skin makes this a bad question. At that rate the skin of the One Above All is the strongest. These are not materials, more of the will of gods for them not to be damaged

Comment: Which Marvel Universe????

Comment: @ThePopMachine – Fair! Back when I asked the question I meant the Comics.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Proto-Adamantium:** The adamantium-vibranium alloy used in Captain America's shield is the strongest human-made material on Earth. It's greatest strength is its nearly immutable nature and resistance to being damaged or changed. The process used to create adamantium requires the material be brought together, shaped and within a fixed amount of time before setting. The process used to create Captain America's shield was similar with the inclusion of vibranium. The process was lost and therefore unable to be repeated.

**Enchanted uru** is not made or normally found on Earth and is both more resistant to damage than normal uru metal but it is not indestructible. It's durable and can be enchanted to be even more damage-resistant but its primary benefit is the ability to bind amazing enchantments to it.

[image: Thor's hammer vs. Hercules' golden Adamantine mace]

*Thor's hammer vs. Hercules' golden Adamantine mace*

To be fair to the Olympians, I will also include **Adamantine** (the material Hercules' mace is made from) to be another mystical metal capable of being enchanted and having its durability enhanced through mystical/scientific forging by Hephaestus, the smith of the Olympian gods.

**Galactus** created the Silver Surfer, so it's safe to say the Silver Surfer is by far the most resistant to damage, considering his job duties and the potential threats he faced, he needed to be. Since he and Galactus both possess matter transmutation and advanced scientific capacity they can create or alter matter to make the strongest materials in the Universe. Other cosmic beings can likely  create similar near-ultimate materials.

In the current iterations of the Marvel Universe, the nature of the most powerful materials would be similar to the nature of the technological capabilities of the species, so more advanced species would likely have better metallurgical technologies. So with that reasoning, I would expect Galactus and the Celestials to have the capacity to create the most powerful materials in the Marvel Universe.

Comment: So, are these the strongest materials in the whole Marvel Universe? Silver Surfer > Echanted Uru > Proto-Adamantium?

Comment: If Proto-Adamantium is so immutable, how did they make it into a shield?

Comment: Likely the same way they made it now. Mixing the components and shaping them before they solidify. The actual method was not known to anyone because the designer of the technology died. The creation of normal Adamantium is the closest approximation to that original design. The process is a secret even to the writers of the Marvel Universe.

Comment: Adamantine should, in all likelihood, be mentioned when discussing the strongest materials in the Marvel universe.  I don't know a ton about it, but Hercules' mace is made of it, and he seemed awfully dismissive of adamantium when compared to his mace's divine adamantine.  (It also appeared on a parallel Wolverine's claws in a recent X-Men comic.)

Answer (score 15):

- Silver Surfer's skin is likely correct. It can survive black holes and being inside the star.
- 2 vs 3 is somewhat correct:

  In Marvel Ultimate Alliance game Thor states that uru is harder than adamantium.

  BUT... Mjolnir was made from **enchanted** uru that was stronger than raw material:

  When Odin removed the enchantments from Mjolnir so that Thor could fight the Hulk HTH, Thor feared that the Hulk would be able to destroy the hammer because its enchantments were removed. (JOURNEY INTO MYSTERY #112).
- Adamantium is NOT the strongest (aside from those 2) - Vibranium/steel alloy that Captain America's shield is made of is stronger. Adamantium was a result of Dr. MacLain trying to replicate the sheid's alloy.

Answer (score 11):

Given all these discussions, Hulk's teeth might be the strongest.

[image: Hulk eats Silver Surfer's head]

Comment: Hahaha, I love Marvel Zombies! And yeah, if all the other answers are correct about the Silver Surfer being so tough, this one gets the trophee. To be fair, I think Surfer could have been weakened in that one, or this could be explained as having happened in an alternative universe. But still, have my upvote!

Answer (score 5):

1. The Runner skin. 
   He is one of the Elders of the Universe.
2. The Silver Surfer skin. 
   He is/was one of the heralds of Galactus. The forces binding together the molecules making up the silvery material that comprises the skin
   of the Surfer are so great that there are  few known forces in the Universe great enough to overcome them.
3. Captain America shield 
   Proto-adamantium is even stronger than true adamantium. It was created by Dr. Myron MacLain and then combined with vibranium to produce the alloy used in Captain America's shield. The shield is so vastly strong that is is renowned EVERYWHERE.
4. The Destroyer armor: it is made of an unknown material, even stronger than uru.
5. Mjölnir (tie) 
   Made with the mystical metal uru, it has been enchanted by Odin with several powers.
6. Adamantine mace of Hercules (tie) 
   Another mystical metal, it is impervious to almost any damage.
7. True adamantium objects
   This is the strongest man made material, almost impossible to damage. Wolverine's skeleton and Ultron's body are made of this.

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi Fantasy Stack Exchange!  Do you have any sources to support your answer?  This would greatly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @N_Soong: In fairness, only one other answer has even one source (and it's narrow and quite brief).

Comment: @Ellesedil true, but if sources can be referenced it strengthens an answer considerably!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I would like to put it like this, you can disagree with me if you like but anyways...

Strongest metalic substance in the Marvel Universe is the Silver Surfer, he is simply too OP to dispute this.

Uru/adamantine are a tie for me, thor hammer vs hercules mace is a tie with enchantments of asgard and olympus also way stronger than anything on earth.

Adamantium/vibrarium are neck and neck, both unique functions and I compare the 2 like this, a heavy tool steel like t10 or t8 vs. Titanium. My logic being for adamantium as a weapon or exo skeleton adamantium is the better metal simply because of its abillity to flex like an excellent katana, and yes edge retention of wolverines claws would also justify this. Vibrarium is stronger but more brittle, it holds its shape no matter what untill the critical stress point is reached making it far better for an armour or a shield.

Comment: This answer doesn't really add any new information, it just reiterates what the other answers have already stated.

Comment: Hello @Joshhinz and welcome to Scifi&Fa SE, please refrain from using the answer section to clarify previous answers or ask for clarifications, use the comments instead, only use the answers to add new unsaid answers, preferably backed with evidence and proof. Use the tour to find it easier to adapt. Enjoy your stay, cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Dargonite is capable of penetrating Adamantium so I would think that it must be a strong alloy as well. To my knowledge, Dargonite only exists in the alternative future timeline of the Guardians of the Galaxy.

Comment: Can you provide any proofs, or tell where was it mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

There is this one metal called [Dargonite](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dargonite), named after [Dargo Ktor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dargo_Ktor_(Earth-8710)). This metal was able to pierce Captain America's shield effortlessly.

Answer (score -2):

Cap has had more than one shield. He has had steel, vibranium,vibranium/adamantium alloy, and finally enchanted uru. The latter being the strongest to date. Really, it's all just semantics and plot devices though. The rules are always changing. The quixotic nature of enchanted uru and its symbiotic relationship with its wielder makes a broad answer to this impossible. Which is as designed. It's always fun to discover a stronger object or character. Also wanted to add that at one point the Hulk bit off silvers surfers' head. Alternate universe though. Don't get me started on alternate universes.

Answer (score -2):

**Proto-Adamantium:** Captain America's shield is composed of a unique Vibranium, Steel alloy, and an unknown third component. It is virtually indestructible.

Comment: But what's the strongest material in the Marvel U? Is it Proto-Adamantium? Do you have any evidence to suggest that?