# Could the Hulk become powerful enough to break adamantium?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, adamantium

The madder the Hulk gets, the stronger and more powerful he becomes. Could he eventually become mad enough to break adamantium?

I've seen a couple of cartoons where it is Hulk vs Wolverine. These typically seem to end in a stalemate. But shouldn't the Hulk be able to keep increasing in strength until he reaches a point where Wolverine's skeleton could be shattered?

Additionally, in the Ultimate Avengers Movie, the Hulk becomes angry enough to be able to lift Thor's hammer.

Comment: I recall in World War Hulk, he fought the X-Men and had a short conversation with Wolverine. He ended up shaking him, causing trauma to Wolverine's head, and just tossing him aside or something. Against Colossus, he *bent his steel arms*. This might be the maddest Hulk has ever been, and I think even he knew he couldn't break adamantium.

Comment: He didn't lift Thor's hammer in the Ultimate Avengers, it was an alternate version of mjolnir.

Comment: Could the Hulk lift a rock so large that he couldn't lift it?

Comment: No, the very premise of proto-adamantium or true adamantium is that it is immune to any form of pure energy manipulation of its structure. The Hulk could never generate the energy required to do it. Only forces which subvert the very nature of reality can. Cosmic beings, All-Fathers/All-Mothers, Infinity Gauntlet, beings who can manipulate the stuff of space-time defining what or how something exists (Galactus, Phoenix, Elders of the Universe, Abstract Beings) are the only candidates for the destruction of the two most indestructible forms of Adamantium in the Earth-616 Universe.

Comment: @Thaddeus the correct term is "All-Parentals", i believe.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It depends on what [form of adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Forms).

- [Proto-Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Proto-Adamantium) - present in Captain America's shield, considered *the absolute most invulnerable item in all of existence*.
- [True Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#True_Adamantium) - present in Wolverine
- [Secondary Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Secondary_Adamantium) - Hulk can break/warp it.
- [Beta Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Beta_Adamantium)
- [Adamantium (Earth-1610)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Adamantium_.28Earth-1610.29) - Hulk *breaks a needle* made of adamantium here.
- [Adamantium (Earth-691)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Adamantium_.28Earth-691.29)
- [Adamantium (Earth-10005)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Adamantium_.28Earth-10005.29)
- [Adamantium Allotropes](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Adamantium_Allotropes)

Adamantium typically, *is almost impossible to destroy or fracture*. From [Marvel's background information on Adamantium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Adamantium#Background_Information):

> *Although True Adamantium was thought to be indestructible, there are
>   at least two known examples of the alloy within the [Earth-616](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-616) reality
>   sustaining damage without molecular manipulation. The first involved
>   Thor focusing all of his strength into striking a small cylinder of
>   adamantium with Mjolnir, which only slightly dented. The second
>   incident involved a battle between Ultron and the Hulk. During the
>   fight, the Hulk punched the robot with enough force to slightly dent
>   it. (Both instances were later revealed to have been only Secondary
>   Adamantium)*

Here is an example of Hulk manipulating the shape of adamantium by squeezing it:

[image]

Hulk has fought Wolverine on many occasions. In [World War Hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Hulk), which may be when Hulk is the maddest I've read, they square off a bit, and Hulk understands that he cannot kill Wolverine. So he shakes him causing a lot of trauma to the brain, to basically knock him out.

[image: Hulk vs Wolverine in World War Hulk]
[image: Hulk vs Wolverine in World War Hulk]

This does have a lot to do with Wolverine's healing factor, but in the very same battle, he fights Colossus in steel form. With much ease, Hulk defeats him by bending his steel arms backwards, essentially breaking them, and removing Colossus from the fight. In no way does he attempt to do this to Wolverine's adamantium skeleton. Time is of concern to Hulk, and maybe that's why he didn't attempt to manipulate adamantium as such.

[image: Hulk bend's Colossus's steel arms backwards]

In [Ultimate Wolverine vs Hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Wolverine_vs._Hulk), Hulk rips Wolverine in half. I'm sure there are other stories where Hulk has ripped a body part off Wolverine, but the weakness is not in the Adamantium, but rather the [ligaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligament).

[image: Ultimate Wolverine vs Hulk]

In regards to Hulk lifting Mjolnir in the Ultimate Avengers movie, which I [asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/how-does-hulk-lift-mjolnir-in-ultimate-avengers-movie), there is a [great answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16431/1042) to that. In short, in the Ultimate version of Mjolnir can be lifted by anyone of sufficient strength, and has nothing to do with worthiness.

**TL;DR**

Yes, depending on what type of adamantium. Has it happened to Wolverine's adamantium? As far as I know, no it hasn't. Theoretically, I suppose it's possible as Hulk has access to unlimited energy the angrier he gets, but I don't think Marvel would ever completely settle it in-universe.

More sources:

- [History and properties of Adamantium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium#History_and_properties_of_adamantium) (wiki)

Comment: Excellent answer. Hopefully your fine work will lay this particular argument to rest.

Comment: Isn't Enchanted Uru stronger that proto-Adamantium? [Link](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/whats-the-strongest-material-in-the-marvel-universe). And, once heard that Hulk did break an adamantium needle, know anything about that?

Comment: @Thecafremo I'm not sure about Enchanted Uru, but for the needle I have that noted in my answer here already next to Adamantium (Earth-1610).

Comment: I think that referenece about not being able to kill Wolverine has more to do with his healing factor, and less to do with his skeleton.

Comment: @JackBNimble I've made an update to my answer with Hulk's battle with Colossus. I think it's relevant because he chooses to manipulate one metal, but not the other.

Comment: This is not entirely topical, but I'm reasonably certain Hulk could rip Wolverine's head off if he really wanted to do so.  As noted in the answer, Wolverine does not have adamantium cartilage/tendons - so while his skeleton would protect his neck from direct blunt force trauma, it would not protect it from upward force from the skull to the vertebra.  Side note: I hate Wolverine, his real invulnerability is the writer.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially Hulk has near limitless strength, but it's dependent on his rage. If he became sufficiently angry, then theoretically, yes, he could break adamantium.

> When transforming into the Hulk, Bruce's DNA realigns in such a way as to make it act like a cosmic antenna absorbing kinetic energy directly from the multiverse. The ability to absorb energy from this unlimited source provides the Hulk with his increased bulk and apparently limitless strength.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_%28comics%29#Powers.2C_appearance.2C_and_abilities)

Answer (score 2):

From last month's *Hulk* #5. Another example of the Hulk breaking adamantium with ease, but this time he does it in a non-enraged state. In the previous example, he had been fighting for some time.

[image: Hulk Breaks Adamantium - Again]

Answer (score 0):

I keep hearing about the Adamantium needle in Ultimate. Here's the thing: the object in question is an Adamantium TIPPED syringe. The syringe is clearly visible in some frames and is clearly largely transparent, and so obviously not made entirely out of Adamantium. They do not say that he broke the Adamantium tip and do not show the Adamantium tip broken. The logical conclusion is that the non-Adamantium portion of the syringe was broken; spilling the contents of the syringe; and not the Adamantium tip.

Answer (score 0):

Hulk issue 300 where doctor strange sent him to the other dimension in exile. Hulk picked up a statue of himself made of adamantium and dug his fingers into it causing cracks. Thor tried to knock it out of his hands and the hammer hitting the statue shattered the windows across the city.

Comment: Is it known if this alternate dimension shares the same rules of physics and adamantium properties as Earth-616? Is there any evidence to support that idea or that contradicts it?

Comment: The Hulk's fingers were only shown to crack the cuboid base the statue was affixed to, not the statue itself. When the statue was originally unveiled in _[Incredible Hulk Vol. 1 #279](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_279)_, it didn't include that cuboid base. It was apparently affixed to the base at a later time, and there's no indication that the base was made of adamantium.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question that's answered in theory. Hulk has limitless strength when enraged enough so yes he could as I said in theory. Marvel however would not consider this to be a viable option as with any super hero/antagonist they need to have a vulnerability and a certain amount of grounding. Take WWH for instance, Hulk was vulnerable to Rick Jones because ultimately he is Banner in mind and Hulk in physical form. The question should be can The Hulk stand on a piece of Lego barefooted without showing any emotion? Hmmm I wonder?

Answer (score -2):

A lot of people don't realise that hulk doesn't just have limitless strength he has unlimited power from the universe by using kenetic energy. This also means that his healing factor has no limit and the only way to kill him is to either use magic to disable his abilitys or to somehow destroy all of the molecules that are his. Plus you need to do all of this quicker than he can heal or gain power. So yeah I think it's pretty possible for him to break or rip adamantium.

Comment: Can you provide some references and citations for your claim, please?  Answers based on opinion may be deleted.

Answer (score -3):

In reference to adamantium. Hulk can simply clap so hard it rattles molecules. Thus no direct force to be redirected simply separating the bonded molecules.

Comment: Do you have some references?  Without references, this is simply your opinion.

Answer (score -4):

I have read many huk comics..ive come to the conclusion that anger and rage are simply overpowering in many ways.all heros use it to win there respective villian countesparts.hulk has pretty much topped any earth and most celestial beings by using rage and anger.and hulk has been beaten by some small time players using leverage...but by no means has he been hurt or killed just for lack of a better term beaten by points like by spiderman, juggernaught etc...i believe thats why there are so many different incarnations of the hulk....just like superman...because if it was just savage hulk the marvel universe would be destroyed or someone like Dr.Strange would be forced to remove him like he did..but for good..or Galactus would just absorb his gamma energy for enernity.anyway enough rant hulk breaks anything if hes mad enough..even superrman.

Answer (score -4):

Hulk does not really have limitless strength.If he did would be able to pick up thor hammer in the 616 universe and so far he could not.He has near limitless strength,not limitless.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you provide references for your answer?

Comment: -1 The hammer's weight is not the reason he can't pick it up.

Answer (score -5):

Punisher Vs. Marvel Universe, Hulk kills Wolverine and snaps his claws.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info, or possibly a picture of the panel in question...?

Comment: NerdAlert - no, that does not happen. Wolverine is killed by electrical discharge by Frank. Hulk is killed (considerably earlier - i think he is the second killed?) by being shot dead when in banner form.